# last_insert_id() vs SELECT Max(ID)

Tags: mysql, lastinsertid

Is using SELECT Max(ID) FROM table safer than using SELECT last_insert_id(), where they run as 2 separate queries?

I'm concerned that before the last_insert_id() can run, another insert will take place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is using SELECT Max(ID) FROM table safer than using SELECT last_insert_id()

Definitely not, never! `LAST_INSERT_ID()` exists exactly for the reason you state: Other clients could have made other inserts. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` always gives you the last inserted ID on the current connection.

[mySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: how does connection pooling affect this?

Comment: Agreed, but remember that you have to be using the same connection, and it must not have been closed and re-opened. You should always run this directly after the INSERT command, before doing anything else - make it a habit, and then when you need the value, you already have it stored in a variable... :)

Comment: Are you connecting to the db through the command line, or using a language such as PHP? that can make a difference...

Answer (score 3):

Using `select max(id)` is just asking for trouble.  It's only a matter of time before two inserts would happen near-simultaneously and you would start to see some craziness in your data.

Comment: Because of isolation levels, typically SELECT is given higher priority - so `SELECT MAX(id) ...` can occur before an insert.  Not good if I can select the value for my insert, just before your insert occurs...