# How to get the just-inserted record ID (mysql)?

Tags: mysql

How to get the just-inserted record ID (mysql)?
What i'll add to query:

```
INSERT INTO `osoby` (`imie`,`nazwisko`)
VALUES ('wartość','wartość2')
```

?
thanks.

Comment: This will INSERT the values, you need SELECT to fetch data

Answer (score 5):

To get the last inserted id use

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html)

Comment: i just show you this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180510/last-insert-id-vs-select-maxid