# How to avoid using max(id) when creating a self-referencing row

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a MySQL table

```
id | ref_id
```

where `ref_id` should be equal to one of the available `id` values (including the one of the same row). `id` is also auto-incremented.

In a stored procedure, I want to add a row to this table where `ref_id` = `id`. I can do it by

```
DECLARE prev_id INT;
SELECT MAX(id) INTO prev_id FROM `table`;
INSERT INTO table (ref_id) VALUES (prev_id + 1)
```

However it is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180556/674976) to use `MAX(id)` for this purpose. I should use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` instead. But how can I do it if I haven't inserted anything else?

Comment: You're not making much sense.

Comment: @Strawberry: it would be great if you could express yourself a bit more clear. What doesn't make sense?

Comment: See how frustrating it is?

Comment: @Strawberry: I am sorry if you don't understand the question. Drew's answer shows that it _is_ at least somewhat clear.

Comment: Drew does at least demonstrate how such a question might be asked

Answer (score 1):

### Schema

```
-- drop table selfie;
create table selfie
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(40) not null,
    ref_id int not null,
    descr varchar(40) not null
);
```

### Stored Procedure

```
drop procedure if exists spInsertOneSelfRef;

DELIMITER $$
create procedure spInsertOneSelfRef
(   pThing varchar(40),
    pRef int, -- 0 if to self, >0 if not 
    pDescr varchar(40)
)
begin
  insert selfie(thing,ref_id,descr) values (pThing,pRef,pDescr);
    -- Moment A
  IF (pRef=0) then
    -- self-reference request, ditch the zero that was just inserted
    set @theId:= last_insert_id();
    update selfie set ref_id=@theId where id=@theId;
    -- MOMENT B
  END IF;
end
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Test it

```
-- truncate table selfie;
call spInsertOneSelfRef('frog',0,'a selfie'); -- 
call spInsertOneSelfRef('cat',1,''); -- 
call spInsertOneSelfRef('mouse',2,''); 
call spInsertOneSelfRef('dog',3,''); -- 
call spInsertOneSelfRef('abcd',0,'a selfie'); --
```

### View results

```
select * from  selfie;
+----+-------+--------+----------+
| id | thing | ref_id | descr    |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
|  1 | frog  |      1 | a selfie |
|  2 | cat   |      1 |          |
|  3 | mouse |      2 |          |
|  4 | dog   |      3 |          |
|  5 | abcd  |      5 | a selfie |
+----+-------+--------+----------+
```

It is possible to insert a `null` into `ref_id` with a few tweaks. And to deal with **concurrency** control in the split second between Moment A and Moment B listed in the stored proc. I leave those to the reader, unless you plead me to do it.

---

### Option B (ref_id schema change)

```
drop table selfie;
create table selfie
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(40) not null,
    ref_id int, -- NULL means I have no parent
    descr varchar(40) not null,
    constraint fk_blahblah foreign key (ref_id) references selfie(id)
);
```

### Test

```
call spInsertOneSelfRef('abcd',null,'no parent'); -- good
call spInsertOneSelfRef('pqrs',1,''); --  good
call spInsertOneSelfRef('zzz',44,''); -- bad (as expected, FK failure)
```

### View

```
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
| id | thing | ref_id | descr     |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | abcd  |   NULL | no parent |
|  2 | pqrs  |      1 |           |
+----+-------+--------+-----------+
```

oh I have a parent now, no problem, update the ref_id column

Comment: For a "selfie" (nice term by the way) you first set ref_id to 0. Wouldn't it fail if I have a constraint (ref_id should be equal to one of the id's) and don't have a 0-id row in the table? I believe your example works because you didn't set up the constraint. Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right, I have done it in the past with such a cheat row

Comment: Nice idea. I'll think it over. Thanks for the detailed answer!